# RS485 Waveform while Receiving Data

Tags: noise, differential, rs485

I was testing the RS485 Circuit, below is my circuit and I connect J5 to my PC using another RS485 to USB converter. In PC through Modscan software I was monitoring the polling and response, a twisted wire used, length of wire is 3 feet only.
[image]
I observe the polling missing some time, generally out of 100 polls, I missed three response. my PC is master and device is Slave.
So I probe the waveforms and observe while in receiving mode I saw a lot of noise on RS485 waveforms. and when transmitting mode such noise is not there.
 see the attached waveform, does any have any idea, this is how an RS485 behave. any suggestion, advise.

I have two channel scope only.
[image]

[image]

layout ( 4 Layer PCB)
[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you testing this circuit? Did you layout a PCB, or are you using some sort of prototyping board?

Comment: yes layout with board.layout image also added in question.

Comment: if your scope inputs are not electrically isolated you can't measure relative to two different grounds at the same time and get sensible results.

Comment: Yes you are right , i break the isolation here, will try to measure again of Ch1 on other side of the isolator.

Comment: RS-485 has three states: high, low, and idle. Are you sure that that USB converter actually works correctly? (Some cheap, broken ones send only low and idle.)

Comment: Does it matter , i have pulled the line high , and another one pulled low, see SCH above.

Comment: Are you using termination resistors? Should be 120 ohm resistors at each end of the cable between A and B lines

Comment: Yes on both ENd, only two device connected on line,

Comment: @Transformer Those scope traces are not representative of what is going on, and it is very likely to be interfering with the system. Make sure your oscope ground is on Field Ground and measure the differential lines only, or on system ground and measure the digital signals only. Also, how are your ground planes distributed?

Comment: Also I open the other converter on pc side ( RS485 to USB) , i found they have used 4.7K pullup on B line and 4.7K pull down on A line of RS485. where in my circuit i used 470E.

Comment: @EdgarBrown :Ground layer layout uploaded above.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the problem (RS485 is not that fast) but that ground distribution does not make sense to me. Field ground should cover all of the area under the 485 lines, signal ground should stay away from them.

Comment: @EdgarBrown you look right , i need to cover rs585 section til connector wihh field ground instead of signal ground.

Comment: 120 ohm Resitor (R9) , need to place near J5 or Near U10 IC?

Answer (score 1):

The ground layout looks wrong. The break between signal ground and field ground should run under U3 splitting it half.

Looking at the schematic, keep everything to the left of U3 over the signal ground. Keep everything to the right of U3 over the field ground.  The way it shown it does not make sense.